Как убрать фото и изменить текст в python telebot
У меня есть сообщение с фотографией и кнопками, как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку фотография у текста удалялась, а текст с кнопками изменялся?
import telebot
from telebot import types
import webbrowser

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    BthPros = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Просмотр ', callback_data='Prosmotr')
    BthZay = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Заявки ✅', callback_data='Zayavki')
    markup.add(BthPros, BthZay)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('‼️ YouTube ‼️', url='https://www.youtube.com'))
    photo1=open('./img/Liga.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1, caption='<b>Добро пожаловать в бот!</b> \n\n Здесь Вы можете посмотреть клубы состоящие в лиге, а так же их составы.\n\n✅ Здесь можно оставить заявку на вступление в лигу. Организаторы рассматривают заявки в кратчайшие сроки!\n\n Руководители клубов могут оставлять заявки на редактирование своего клуба.\n\nА ещё подписывайтесь на наш YouTube Канал! ', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    markup3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    BthKlub = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Клубы ⚽️', callback_data='Klubi')
    BthVstup = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вступление ✅', callback_data='Vstuplenie')
    BthNaz = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад ⬅️', callback_data='Nazad')
    markup2.add(BthKlub, BthNaz)
    markup3.add(BthVstup, BthNaz)
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'Prosmotr':
            bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.chat.id, text='<b>Клубы</b> ⚽️\n\n Выберете клуб лиги, чтобы посмотреть его состав игроков! ', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup2)
        elif call.data == 'Zayavki':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.chat.id, text='<b>Заявки</b> ✅\n\n Оставьте заявку на вступление в «Liga V»! После одобрения или отклонения заявки вам придёт уведомление ', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup3)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['youtube'])
def youtube(message):
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)*

Нужно, чтобы удалилось фото и изменился текст с кнопками
